# How to write process ID and get exit code of the next to last command

Tags: bash, exit-code

I want to run a command, write the process id instantly to a file when the command started and afterwards get the exit status of the command. This means, while the process id has to be written instantly, I want the exit status only when the initial command has finished.

The following statement will unfortunately run the command, write the process id instantly but it won't wait for the command to be finished. Furthermore I will only get the exit status of the echo command, not of the initial command

**command** in my case is rdiff-backup.

How do I need to modify the statement?

```
<command> & echo $! > "/pid_file"
RESULT=$?
if [ "$RESULT" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "Finished with errors"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `wait` on the background process to get its exit status:

```
_command_for_background_ & echo $! > pid_file
: ... do other things, if any ...
#
# it is better to grab $? on the same line to prevent any
# future modifications inadvertently breaking the strict sequence
#
wait $(< pid_file); child_status=$?
if [[ $child_status != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Finished with errors"
fi
```

Comment: Seems to work with me. One question: Why did you call the variable **child_status**? Isn't **_command_for_background_** the parent process who's exit code I store in variable **child_status** and the **echo $!** the child process? This is probably just a naming thing, but I don't want to get confused...

Comment: Well I guess technically both `command_for_background` and `echo` are children, but the one you're interested in is `command_for_background`. Since the latter is the one you are `wait`ing for, it makes sense to call it the child.